# How to set background image for JPanel in netbeans?

Tags: java

i am using netbeans IDE problem is how to set background image for JPanel without using JLabel. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Seriously, who upvoted this twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward.

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
    Image image;
    public ImagePanel(Image image){
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0,0, this);
    }
}
```

If you want more complex have a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/cmoct-sourcecode/source/browse/trunk/src/com/joey/software/imageToolkit/ImagePanel.java) link. This has a couple of settings like fit image to panel...